# Hide Column Names in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Is it possible to hide the first row ( the column definitions) in ag-grid?
I just want to display the data in the table and excluding the column headings.

Comment: Set the header height to zero. There is an api method for setting header height.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add `headerHeight` property on your component and set this to 0 which will hide the headers. Like so:

```
<ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [headerHeight]="0">
 </ag-grid-angular>
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular) StackBlitz.

Comment: with this solution I am able to hide the headers. but How to remove separator line between header and 1st row ?

Comment: Works charmly, ty.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers seemed to work for me with Vue. I used CSS to hide the header. I gave my grid an ID and then I hide the grid header.

```
#my-grid .ag-header {
   display:none;
}
```