# How to hide ag grid header for footer aligned grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

How to hide header in ag grid. Trying with headerHeight="0" but that method not working

```
<ag-grid-angular
#footerGrid
style="flex:none ;height: 140px;"
class="ag-theme-alpine"
headerHeight="0"
[rowData]="footerData"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs"
[gridOptions]="footerOptions"
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

```
<ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [headerHeight]="0">
 </ag-grid-angular>
```

maybe this could help : [Hide Column Names in ag-grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424105/hide-column-names-in-ag-grid)

Comment: Tried that but same thing . One interesting fact , same code working on new angular project , but in existing project not working