# How to hide column header in Ag-grid?

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

In my vue.js application, I have a requirement where I want to hide the column headers in the ag-grid but want to display the rows.

I used below property to hide the column headers.

```
headerHeight: 0
```

with this I can able to hide the column headers but still the line separator between header and first row is visible. How can I add hide the separator line as well ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide Column Names in ag-grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424105/hide-column-names-in-ag-grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by tweaking the `ag-header` style along with the `headerHeight`.

In `ag-grid` template **:**

```
:headerHeight="0"
```

In `CSS` side **:**

```
.ag-header {
  border-bottom: 0px !important
}
```

Working Plunker **:** [Hide ag-grid column header](https://plnkr.co/edit/YyXOEA566cddWAxS)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it without using headerHeight and css is to only use display: none; in the css. however, if you have multiple ag-grids in your application you should define a unique ID to the ag-grid so the other grids dont get overwritten by your css.

```
//customcss.css
#uniqueAGGridID .ag-root .ag-header {
  display: none;
}


//file where grid is.
<ag-grid-vue
      id="uniqueAGGridID"
      class="ag-theme-balham h-100"
      :grid-options="gridOptions"
      :column-defs="columnDefs"
    />
```